# Error when running Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I got this error when running Karma:

> Some of your tests did a full page reload! Chrome 60.0.3112 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 11 of 26 (skipped 1) ERROR (0.081 secs / 0.068 secs)

I have searched extensively on this but even on Github there is no solution for this. [Issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1101)

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Edric I can't show the code but if there anything specific, then please tell which will help to solve the issue.